# Mapping between PWM counts and joint angle in ros_canopen

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using **ros_canopen**, which is an awsome package, to communicate with my robot.

By far, I modified the below yaml parameters to deal with the mapping between PWM counts and jont angle.

```
default:
  pos_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(pos)*1000)"
  pos_from_device: "deg2rad(obj6064)/1000" 
  vel_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(vel)*1000)" 
  vel_from_device: "deg2rad(obj606C)/1000"
```

Is there a way to use transmission ratio in URDF and define only a parameter of encoder resolution in the above yaml?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247820/mapping-between-pwm-counts-and-joint-angle-in-ros_canopen/) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is not implemented (yet?).
(https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/195)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1